# does Magento 2.3 have wishlist clean up functionality

Tags: magento2.3.2, wishlist

I just want to ask if there is a wishlist  clean up functionality because I got a client that complain because his wishlist was deleted systematically.

we are currently using Magento version. 2.3.2.

thanks.

Comment: No there are no any such kind of funcationality.

Answer (score 0):

**No there are no any wishlist clean up functionality.**

> **Run below SQL and then wishlist is empty for all users.**

```
TRUNCATE TABLE wishlist_item;

TRUNCATE TABLE wishlist_item_option;

TRUNCATE TABLE email_wishlist;
```

***Note: Do not clean wishlist table data.***